# A link reveals an image and hides itself

Tags: javascript, html, visibility

I'm completely new to coding, and I want to know how to code a link that reveals a hidden image at the same time as hiding itself using HTML. From what I've gathered, this should work:

```html
<a href="javascript:onoff()" id="QRText" onclick="myFunction();"=>Click to reveal QR code</a>
<img hidden alt="QR Code" id="revealonclick" src="https://erallie.weebly.com/uploads/1/1/8/6/118611729/published/qr-code-erallie-s-app.png?1532624405">


<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("The app is in the form of a webpage. Don't forget to add the webpage to your homescreen!");
</script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            function onoff() {
                if (document.getElementById)
                 document.getElementById("QRText").style.visibility = "hidden";
                 if (document.getElementById)
                 document.getElementById("revealonclick").style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        </script>
```

The hiding the link works, and the notification works, but for some reason, it doesn't seem to work when I try to add multiple arguments into one function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is a syntax error in your function `myFunction`. Is that your full code?

Answer (score 0):

There's a missing closing bracket in your myFunction definition, first of all. That may just be an error when pasting your code here though.

You're using style.visibility to try to make your image visible, however that's not what was making it invisible in the first place. If you want to use the Visibility attribute to make it visible, you need to use the same one to make it invisible.

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert("The app is in the form of a webpage. Don't forget to add the webpage to your homescreen!");
}

function onoff() {
  if (document.getElementById) {
    document.getElementById("QRText").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("revealonclick").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:onoff()" id="QRText" onclick="myFunction();"=>Click to reveal QR code</a>
<img style="visibility: hidden;" alt="QR Code" id="revealonclick" src="https://erallie.weebly.com/uploads/1/1/8/6/118611729/published/qr-code-erallie-s-app.png?1532624405">
```

This works, however you'll notice that the image appears in the location where it would if your link was still visible. This is because using visibility: hidden makes the item invisible, but it still takes up room in the DOM. To have it disappear "more completely", you can use "display: none;" and "display: inline;" or "display: block;" instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of syntax errors in your code. The following should work.

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert("The app is in the form of a webpage. Don't forget to add the webpage to your homescreen!");
}

function onoff() {
  var elem1 = document.getElementById("QRText");
  var imgElem = document.getElementById("revealonclick");
  if (elem1 && imgElem) {
    elem1.style.visibility = "hidden";
    imgElem.style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:onoff()" id="QRText" onclick="myFunction()">Click to reveal QR code</a>
<img style="visibility: hidden;" alt="QR Code" id="revealonclick" src="https://erallie.weebly.com/uploads/1/1/8/6/118611729/published/qr-code-erallie-s-app.png?1532624405">
```